# MVC 3 Cant get streamed images to show in Internet explorer or Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a bit of a issue with getting my streamed images to show in Internet Explorer or Google Chrome but they appear fine in FireFox. I've pasted my code below, I've put it together using a load of bits and bobs I've found googleing.

```
public ImageResult GetPhotoS(string photoID, int userID, int? galleryID)
    {
        if (galleryID == null)
        {
            string thumbLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}\\Pics\\{2}_thumb.jpg", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotoLocation"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name), photoID);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(thumbLocation, FileMode.Open))
            {
                FileStreamResult fsResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
                ImageResult result = new ImageResult(ReadFully(fsResult.FileStream), "image/jpeg");

                return result;
            }
        }
    }

private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

public class ImageResult : ActionResult
{
    public String ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
    public String SourceFilename { get; set; }

    //This is used for times where you have a physical location
    public ImageResult(String sourceFilename, String contentType)
    {
        SourceFilename = sourceFilename;
        ContentType = contentType;
    }

    //This is used for when you have the actual image in byte form
    //  which is more important for this post.
    public ImageResult(byte[] sourceStream, String contentType)
    {
        ImageBytes = sourceStream;
        ContentType = contentType;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.ContentType = ContentType;

        //Check to see if this is done from bytes or physical location
        //  If you're really paranoid you could set a true/false flag in
        //  the constructor.
        if (ImageBytes != null)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes);
            stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            response.TransmitFile(SourceFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm displaying the images using the following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoS", "Image", new { photoID = photo.ID, userID = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) })" alt="@photo.Description" />
```

All I get from Chrome and IE are the usual red crosses where the image should be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `ImageResult`? What is `ReadFully`? Could you please show your real code? I wonder what answers do you expect without showing your code.

Comment: I've added the extra code apologise I wasn't trying to hide it just doing 100 things at once and didn't think, its one of those days!

Comment: Have you tried using the content type of 'image/jpeg'?  I'm not sure 'image/jpg' is as widely accepted as valid across all browsers.

Comment: I know Chrome can be particularly finicky about content length in the header - have you tried to set a content length header entry in your response?

Comment: Open up Chrome's debug mode and look at the network inspector then compare what headers come back for the file based mode vs the streamed mode.

Comment: try Response.Flush() at the end of ExecuteResult()

Comment: I can't really see much difference in the headers the main and obvious one is a normal image is returned with a status code of 304 Not Modified and the streamed images are returned with 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Ok feel really silly now but in my defence I did say it was one of those days. When setting the thumbLocation I used Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) that should have been userID. The reason it worked on Firefox and not IE or Chrome was because I was logged into the site in Firefox while I was testing something hence Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) had a value when I opened it in the other browsers it didn't, hence no images. Thanks for all the quick responses tho. I'm now off to sit in the corner for a while!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a FileContentResult?

```
public FileContentResult GetPhotoS(string photoID, int userID, int? galleryID)
    {
        if (galleryID == null)
        {
            string thumbLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}\\Pics\\{2}_thumb.jpg", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotoLocation"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name), photoID);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(thumbLocation, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return File(ReadFully(stream), "image/jpeg");
            }
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find gallery");
    }
```

This also seems a bit redundant, why not just concatenate a URL using the photoId, userId, and galleryId? Are the images stored outside of the webroot?